# Is the number of connections used by redisson sum of subscriptionConnectionPoolSize and connectionPoolSize?

Tags: redisson

I want to understand how to calculate the total number of connections used by redisson. My understanding is it is the sum subscriptionConnectionPoolSize  and connectionPoolSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total amount of possible connections is limited by:

Redis nodes amount * (subscriptionConnectionPoolSize + connectionPoolSize)

Comment: So what is `nettyThreads` responsible for? is it related at all?

Comment: Netty threads are responsible for Redis data sending/decoding